# Google Cloud Endpoints EOFException

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gzip, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the method below in AppEngine:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "authed", path = "greeting/authed")
public HelloGreeting authedGreeting(User user) {
    ...
}
```

My doInBackground method in Android AsyncTask:

```
HelloGreeting hg = null;
try {
    hg = service.authed().execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("error", e.getMessage(), e);
}
return hg;
```

I encountered the ff error:

```
/_ah/api/.../v1/greeting/authed: java.io.EOFException
```

In logcat:

```
Problem accessing /_ah/api/.../v1/greeting/authed. Reason: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort
```

It only work when calling non-auth method. How to fix it?

Im using the local server.

Comment: Is this against the local server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was running into a similar problem with when making a call for inserting values.  Mine differs slightly because I am not using authentication, however I was getting the same exception.  I am using **appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8**.  I was able to make other endpoint calls having this error.  I looked at the generated code and the difference that I saw with the working calls versus the non-working calls, was the HttpMethod.  The failing call was defined as `"POST"`.  I was able to change this using the annotation attribute `httpMethod=ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET` in the `@ApiMethod` annotation.

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET, name = "insertUserArtist", path = "insertUserArtist")
```

I then regenerated the client code and I was able to make the call without getting the dreaded `EOFException`.  I am not sure why POST doesn't work properly but changing it to GET worked.  This does possibly present some questions on how much data can be sent across and should be addressed (possibly a library issue).  I am going to look into creating a demonstration app to submit to Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you passed an "entity" object, then the POST will work.  If you are passing primitive data type, you'll be stuck with using HttpMethod.GET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the local dev server,
then add the following snippet in MyApi.Builder to set it up properly after setting root url.

```
    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                    abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                }
            })
```

Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints